# Best way to design cross-platform multi-content-type file format?

Tags: javascript, c++, android, xml, file-format

I need to redesign a file format for a set of applications ( desktop/online/mobile.. ) which is to contain a set of non-linear data and multiple images.
I do not want to make it one large XML with embedded images as:

- first of all it could grow to a size that would be for example slow to parse using javascript
- second of all I want it to be editable 'by hand'.

The compression is not necessary. I just want to distribute this as a single files. I would like my solution to be as cross-platform as possible.

What I made up recently is a *.tar.gz archive with xmls and images inside.

- The desktop (C++ / Qt) version of my application is reading the file using zlib (which was hard to code but works).
- The online version is using PHP (execing tar) to uncompress the file (caches contents in database) and passes xmls and images to javascript via ajax.
- When I came to develop an android version I'm kinda stuck and I don't know how to read it here.

I was wondering if there is a better / simpler solution to achieve this?

Solutions I found are for example:

- Blender .blend files http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_%28software%29#File_format But this is not readable without any special tool.
- OpenOffice files which are in fact zips.
  But I guess there is no big difference using this or tar.gz. It still would be a problem to read it on a mobile platform or with javascript.

Probably there is no 'best way' to do this but i hope there are some widely used solutions?

I will appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: You could easily decompress a zip/tar with a standard Java Android app, but I'm not sure it's possible in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will meet your "editable by hand" criteria, but to make a single-file, cross-platform binary format, [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) are very useful and efficient, and work across major platforms and languages.

If "editable by hand" is critical, with a little extra work, you can write simple utilities using your own message libraries to support creating/updating/deleting portions of existing files (e.g. extract out images for editing, and support replacing them.)

Answer (score 0):

If it must be editable in JavaScript, perhaps [JSON](http://json.org/) might be a good option? You can insert pictures/video/other files by using base64 data url encoding, which is supported in Javascript and many other languages.